Continuously add text boxes in userform as I scan barcodes
I'm working on a UserForm that displays product information including the barcode, product name, and price, all sourced from a 'Products' tab.
The barcode scanning and display of product name and price works the first item.
When scanning a second item the product name and price labels didn't update.
Additionally, upon attempting to scan a third item, a new TextBox failed to appear.
Private Sub BarcodeTextBox_Change()
    Dim scannedCode As String
    Dim foundProduct As Range
    
    ' Get the scanned barcode from the TextBox
    scannedCode = BarcodeTextBox.Text
    
    ' Search for the scanned product code in the "Products" worksheet
    Set foundProduct = Worksheets("Products").Columns(1).Find(What:=scannedCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not foundProduct Is Nothing Then
        ' Product found, retrieve information
        Dim productName As String
        Dim productPrice As Double
        
        ' Retrieve product name and price from adjacent cells
        productName = foundProduct.Offset(0, 1).Value
        productPrice = foundProduct.Offset(0, 2).Value
        
        ' Update labels to display product information
        ProductNameLabel.Caption = "Product Name: " & productName
        ProductPriceLabel.Caption = "Price: $" & Format(productPrice, "0.00")
        
        ' Add a new TextBox below BarcodeTextBox for continuous scanning
        AddNewBarcodeTextBox
        SendKeys "{TAB}", False
    Else
        ' Product not found, clear labels
        ProductNameLabel.Caption = ""
        ProductPriceLabel.Caption = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewBarcodeTextBox()
    ' Add a new TextBox below BarcodeTextBox
    Dim newTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Set newTextBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    
    With newTextBox
        .Top = BarcodeTextBox.Top + BarcodeTextBox.Height + 5 ' Position below the BarcodeTextBox
        .Left = BarcodeTextBox.Left
        .Width = BarcodeTextBox.Width
        .Height = BarcodeTextBox.Height
        .Name = "NewBarcodeTextBox"
        .TabStop = True
        .SetFocus
    End With
End Sub

Picture of the UserForm:


The 3rd is hidden below the 2nd, you don't increment the Top for the 3rd .Top = BarcodeTextBox.Top + BarcodeTextBox.Height + 5

@Jeremy Thompson Thank you for the reply! If I replace my code, starting with Private Sub AddNewBarcodeTextBox(), with your code, then the process stops at Private count As Integer

The 3rd is hidden below the 2nd, you don't increment the Top for the 3rd:
Private count As Integer

Private Sub AddNewBarcodeTextBox()
    ' Add a new TextBox below BarcodeTextBox
    Dim newTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Set newTextBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    count = count + 1
    With newTextBox
        .Top = BarcodeTextBox.Top + (count * (BarcodeTextBox.Height + 5)) ' Position below the BarcodeTextBox
        .Left = BarcodeTextBox.Left
        .Width = BarcodeTextBox.Width
        .Height = BarcodeTextBox.Height
        .Name = "NewBarcodeTextBox" & count
        .TabStop = True
        .SetFocus
    End With
End Sub


Thank you for the reply! If I replace my code, starting with Private Sub AddNewBarcodeTextBox(), with your code, then the process stops at Private count As Integer

I'm not sure what that means, "the process stops at Private count As Integer". Simply declare Private count As Integer at the top of the file above both methods. Also learn to step through the code and work out what exactly is going on, use YouTube video's to learn debugging.
